# Highstock remove unwanted space from chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a highstock area spline chart with categories on the Y-axis. No points on the chart will ever go over the Top category, but I have an unwanted space above the top category 'Alarm'.

[image]

My Y-axis contains `min` and `max` which I use to always display all of the categories. If I set the max to 8 I lose the Alarm Category and the empty line is still there.

Here is my Y-Axis code

```
    yAxis: {
        categories: ['Unknown', 'State 1', 'Disarmed', 'Armed', 'Service Timed', 'Unauthorised', 'Alert', 'Watch', 'Alarm'],
        min: 0,
        max: 9,
        title: {
            useHTML: true,
            text: 'Alert Type'
        },
        opposite: false,
        labels: {
            x: 0,
            y: 8
        },
    },
```

Is there anyway which I can **only** display enough 'lines' for my Y-axis categories and no unwanted lines which will never be used?

All help is appreciated.

Comment: @NicolasR It is set to 9 because there are 9 Categories, if i set it to 8 I lose the top category.

Comment: Sorry I misread your texte as it was already described. Maybe you could add more details of your highchart implementation to get more feedback

Comment: have you tried `yAxis: { endOnTick: true},`?

Comment: @wf4 I have yes, but it didn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: @JamesTordoff you really should create a jsfiddle or working snippet to demonstrate the problem, with what you have provided it's not possible for me to replicate the problem.

Comment: You have 9 categories, but you set y axis range to span from 0 to 9 which means that it will span for 10 categories. Set max to 8 http://jsfiddle.net/ye6f6mna/